# Date picker popping wherever i click on screen

Tags: android, xml, datepicker

### DATE PICKER POPPING wherever i click on the screen!!

**search_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E1E1E1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantDesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#726E6D" >

            <!-- Back Button -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantSearchActivityBackButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/black_button"
                android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                android:paddingRight="13dp"
                android:paddingTop="13dp"
                android:text="BACK"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <!-- Restaurant Description page name -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantSearchActivityName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/CITY_ID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID"
            android:layout_width="256dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:onClick="selectDate" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2.5" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Type"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/BreakfastRG_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Breakfast" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/LunchRG_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Lunch" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/DinnerRG_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Dinner" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:onClick="selectDate"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SEARCH_BUTTON_ID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="Search" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <include
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            layout="@layout/screen_bottombar_photodesc" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to resolve this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have onClick event in the RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:onClick="selectDate"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >
```

Corrected layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E1E1E1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantDesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#726E6D" >

            <!-- Back Button -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantSearchActivityBackButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/black_button"
                android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                android:paddingRight="13dp"
                android:paddingTop="13dp"
                android:text="BACK"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <!-- Restaurant Description page name -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantSearchActivityName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/CITY_ID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID"
            android:layout_width="256dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:onClick="selectDate" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2.5" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Type"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/BreakfastRG_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Breakfast" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/LunchRG_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Lunch" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/DinnerRG_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Dinner" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SEARCH_BUTTON_ID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="Search" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <include
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            layout="@layout/screen_bottombar_photodesc" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both your text view `DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID` and your (lower) RelativeLayout have `android:onClick="selectDate"` which will open your date picker when either is clicked. I don't know how much of the screen either takes up (im a bad human xml parser) but I have a feeling that is part of your problem here. (I cant directly test it as I dont have eclipse around right now)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have declared `android:onClick="selectDate"` in both date `editText` and `RelativeLayout`.
Remove it form `RelativeLayout`
Paste the following code in your search_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E1E1E1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantDesc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#726E6D" >

            <!-- Back Button -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantSearchActivityBackButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/black_button"
                android:paddingBottom="13dp"
                android:paddingLeft="13dp"
                android:paddingRight="13dp"
                android:paddingTop="13dp"
                android:text="BACK"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <!-- Restaurant Description page name -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TopNavigationBarRestaurantSearchActivityName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Search"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/CITY_ID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/DATE_EDIT_TEXT_ID"
            android:layout_width="256dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:onClick="selectDate" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="2.5" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Type"
            android:textSize=" 15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/BreakfastRG_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Breakfast" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/LunchRG_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Lunch" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/DinnerRG_ID"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:background="@drawable/yourbuttonbackground"
                android:button="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Dinner" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="172dp"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SEARCH_BUTTON_ID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="Search" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#E1E1E1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <include
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            layout="@layout/screen_bottombar_photodesc" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but i think your problem is `<requestFocus />`, try to remove it and see what is happen.